# Как найти функцию, которая изменяет размер div

Tags: javascript, dom, отладка, javascript-events

Вот что имеем в исходном коде, то что отдает php на сервере

```
<div class="box-content" id="newDivCont" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
```

Когда загружаю страничку с очисткой кеша, то в хроме в консоли вижу вот это

```
<div class="box-content" id="newDivCont" style="padding-bottom: 20px; height: 914.006px;">
```

Т.е. какой-то скрипт поменял высоту, причем неверно - из-за этого смещения идут. Далее, если обновляю страницу через F5, в консоли уже видим исходный код

```
<div class="box-content" id="newDivCont" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
```

Как отследить кто это делает?
Через консоль, через Event Listeners не получается это сделать, не находит.

Comment: Ну если это ваш сайт, то в коде вы не можете поискать какая функция меняет?

Comment: Могу, но это было тяжело сделать, куча js файлов. В итоге в файлах ничего не было, было в самой страничке прописано.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо не через обработчики событий, а через изменение dom-элемента.

На вкладке Elements его правой кнопкой, <kbd>Break on...</kbd> <kbd>attribute modifications</kbd>

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Спасибо! Да это работает. Действительно виден стек,  и кто что делает.